# ¿Dónde van los scripts de javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Cuándo escribo un script en javascript o jquery, este debe estar debajo del elemento que modifica o puede estar en el header? Pregunto porque si pongo este script en el header no funciona el eventhandler click y no hace nada. Si lo pongo debajo del botón, sí funciona.

Gracias.

```
<head>
<script> $("#boton").click(function(){window.alert("Prueba")})</script>
<title>HomeWork Ajax</title>
</head>

<body>
<button id='boton'>Ver Amigos</button>
</body>
```

Comment: Si lo pones "arriba" el script se ejecuta sin que siquiera se haya creado el botón.  Por tanto `$("#boton")` no va a existir, y por eso "no hace nada". En realidad sí se ejecuta lo que no hay "#boton" al que agregarle ningún evento. Si quieres que la ejecución del script se ejecute solo después de parseado el html usa `<script defer></script>` o bien ya que usas jquery `$(document).ready(()=>{ \\ tu codigo})`

Comment: ¡Gracias! Lo voy a probar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

La practica de utilizar JavaScript requiere conocer que para manipular elementos del DOM estos deben existir antes, por eso la mayoría los pondrá al final de la carga del código HTML, si precargas un script que hace una llamada a un elemento, el script se ejecutara en el momento de la llamada y devolverá un error porque el elemento al que hace la llamada no ha sido cargado todavía.

Colocarlos en el head, solo requiere que agregues un listener que espere a que el DOM este cargada antes de empezar a manipularlo.